# Loading json data into hive tables using spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hive, pyspark, hiveql

I am trying to load a dataframe into json data Here is my sample data

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
val df = Seq((2012, 8, "Batman", 9.8), (2012, 8, "Hero", 8.7), (2012, 7, "Robot", 5.5), (2011, 7, "Git", 2.0)).toDF("year", "month", "title", "rating")
```

I am converting the data into json object

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val finalJsonDF = df.select(to_json(struct("year", "month", "title", "rating"))).as("test")
```

I can view the data, but the data structure is

```
structstojson(named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), year, NamePlaceholder(), month, NamePlaceholder(), title, NamePlaceholder(), rating))
```

Now I am trying to create a table and load the dataframe into the table

```
finalJsonDF.show()

finalJsonDF.write.json("s3://tmp/test")

spark.sql(""" drop table if exists test.sample_test""")

spark.sql("""create external table test.sample_test 
(
test struct<year:String,
month:String, 
title:String, 
rating:String>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
stored as TextFile
location "s3://tmp/test"
""")

spark.sql(""" describe test.sample_test""").show()

spark.sql(""" select * from  test.sample_test""").show()
```

All I can see is null rows.